# When am I wiser than the OP?

Tags: discussion, downvotes, downvote-reason

I have been responding to
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47809922/how-to-escape-plain-text-looking-like-variable-interpolation-in-perl-regular-exp?noredirect=1#comment82637529_47809922)

The OP made it clear in his original post that he was dealing with XML data, but insisted that his question was specifically about regular expressions, and would brook no advice that a proper parser was the right way to go, to the extent of down-voting an answer that focussed on the XML

I can be very grumpy at times and I'm sure I could have phrased some of the comments better so I have reported the thread for moderator regulation. But what would the better option have been?

I believe that the OP's down vote on the XML solution was inappropriate, but those votes aren't up for discussion. Should I have just walked away after the start of hostility?

Comment: _Should I have just walked away after the start of hostility?_ Yes. No need to engage when things escalate.

Comment: something something how can you be sure it's their downvote something something? anyway, I do believe that, when OP of a question sees something that, according to them, literally does not apply to their question, does not answer it, a downvote is the correct thing to do, isn't it?

Comment: We all learn differently, if OP doesn't want to hear "how it could have been better" then let him in the dark, he will later discover the light by himself... later...

Comment: Silence is golden ...

Comment: @FélixGagnon-Grenier: See my comment on your answer.

Comment: I'm getting a flurry of down votes and little advice. I have written dozens of answers to questions that ask how to process XML using regular expressions, and the OP has always been delighted to find that there is a "proper" way, especially one that avoids writing regular expressions. Am I being advised that I should always have answered those questions literally, ignoring best practice?

Comment: @Borodin Who has told you to do that, or even implied that that would be appropriate?

Comment: @Servy: To do what?

Comment: @Borodin "Am I being advised that I should always have answered those questions literally, ignoring best practice?"

Comment: @Servy: No one. It is the antithesis of my usual approach: that I should read between the lines and advise about things the OP didn't think they were asking.

Comment: @Servy: Why do you ask?

Comment: @Servy: *"Am I being advised..."* is a question. I posed it because the core of my post is about whether my approach was correct, and what may be better. No one has offered an opinion. Why are you suggesting that I already have an answer to my question?

Comment: "I posed it because the core of my question is whether my approach was correct." And yet the question you actually asked was, "Should I have just walked away after the start of hostility?"  If you wanted to know if it's appropriate to suggest a solution to an underlying problem, instead of a question asked, when you see problems with solving just the question asked, you could have asked about it.  "Why are you suggesting that I already have an answer to my question?" For the question you actually asked, yes, I *am* saying you already have an answer to that question.

Comment: @Servy: The question I asked was *"When am I wiser than the OP?"*. As I hope you know, subsidiary questions are points for consideration. Are you eager to run this as if it were a court of law?

Comment: @Borodin Which is a meaningless question that makes no sense and is entirely off topic.  And also isn't asking anything about whether questions should be answered literally or not.

Comment: @Servy: I think you need to substantiate that. From my point of view it is your distractions that are *way* off topic. I am sure that most subscribers will understand my meaning.

Comment: It is irrelevant to anyone here whether you're wiser than the OP or not.  It doesn't matter to the site, or anyone on meta, or the situation you've described, whether you're wiser than the OP or if they're wiser than you.

Comment: @Servy: As I said, *"I am sure that most subscribers will understand my meaning"*. If you're arbitrarily imposing legalistically accurate and lengthy terminology then I question your authority to do so.

Comment: Oh, so you asked a completely off topic and meaningless question because you just expected everyone here to use their mind reading devices to know what you actually wanted to ask, even though you asked something completely different (well, multiple completely different things).  Now you know that you should ask the question you actually want answered, rather than asking something unrelated and hoping people guess what you really wanted to know.

Comment: @bluefeet: *"No need to engage when things escalate"* But it is notoriously hard to tell when things are *escalating*.

Comment: @Borodin You stated you saw the "start of hostility" that's the point you walk away.

Comment: @bluefeet: That is a retrospective observation. As with **Servy's** silliness, I suspect that I pulled out of it way too late. Debate is not one of my best skills, and not one that I expect to need when I am simply asking the community's opinion in a *discussion*.

Comment: _That is a retrospective observation_. Well how in the world do you expect anyone to answer your main question then? _Should I have just walked away after the start of hostility?_ is just nonsense if your latest contention is that you didn’t know about the hostility in the first place. If I didn’t know better I’d say you were being deliberately obtuse here

Comment: Wait... when the hostilities with OP started, you didn't realize it. Correct? Then how does the 'yes you should have walked away' helps you? When the situation happened you couldn't see it was happening... you need to identify these situations faster, not be told what to do once you realize it (you seem to be aware of what needs to be done, anyway)

Comment: To add some context have a look at the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47809922/3) The question _was_ about XML initially, and the OP was tackling an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem) which was why I answered as I did.

Answer (score 10):

> and would brook no advice that a proper parser was the right way to go, to the extent of down-voting an answer that focussed on the XML

OP downvoted an answer on the basis of it being about xml, hence off-topic for their question. **That is precisely what downvotes are for.** If an answer does not actually answer the question, it's perfectly fine for the author of said question to downvote these answers. Other people are free to upvote if they feel the answers are useful.

The score of the answer will in turn be a signal to OP that they may be erring.

The behaviour you describe, out of context, is perfectly fine, and OPs should not be afraid to downvote answers they feel do not answer their questions.

---

This is actually an answer. Yes, walking away is literally the thing to do at the beginning of "hostilities".

Comment: I hoped you would take a look at the post. The OP commented *"Down vote because the RegExp vs. XML-Parser discussion is off-topic"*. So yes it *"it really is OP that downvoted an answer on the basis of it being about xml"*

Comment: @Borodin I made it clear that OP in this case really did downvote, even though it's rather orthogonal to this answer. The situation I am using as example literally takes into account OP being the downvoter.

Comment: So is your contention that every question should be answered completely literally, and we should never suggest any other aspects that could be relevant? Even worse, are you saying that, if we *dare* to mention anything outside the immediate scope of the question we should expect our offerings to be down voted?

Comment: @Borodin I believe I have expressed rather explicitely both these concerns, first by answering you with aspects relevant to your question but not directly in line with the actual question sentence, and secondly by offering that post as vote target. I have never said anything about answering only directly to questions, I am trying to explain to you that OP have the right to vote. As you probably did on this answer.

Comment: Okay, then that is enough. I have understood your point, I disagree, and so we think differently. All I can say is that, if everyone followed your ideals, I think that *Stack Overflow* would be a lesser place.

Comment: @Borodin You think SO would be a worse place if people voted based on whether or not they think the post is useful?  Why do you think that would make SO worse, and how do you think people are voting now that you think is better?

Comment: To clarify perhaps - the first draft of the question actually was about parsing XML. With Regex. I was offering an alternative approach that used the fact that there's a readily available parser to solve the problem.